# Event on disposing a window

Tags: java, swing

i have this program in java when you click on View tables and view all
a windows appears, i need to hide the first one and on closing the second on ,

the first one to become visible again

i have no idea how to refer to an object from these classes since i have created them like 
new Main(); and new View(); :)

this is one class:

```java
package CarManager;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static int width = 400;
    static int height = width / 16 * 9;
    static String title = "Car Manager";
    JButton viewTables = new JButton("View tables");
    JButton clients = new JButton("Clients");
    JButton search = new JButton("Search");
    JButton viewCars = new JButton("View all");
    JButton viewRent = new JButton("Rent a car");
    JButton viewBuy = new JButton("Buy a car");
    JButton viewAccessory = new JButton("Accessory");

    public Main() {

        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(width, height);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res\\background2.jpg"));
        add(background);
        background.setSize(width, height);
        add(viewTables);
        add(clients);
        add(search);
        viewTables.setBounds(20, 20, 110, 30);
        clients.setBounds(20, 70, 110, 30);
        search.setBounds(20, 120, 110, 30);

        viewTables.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                add(viewCars);
                viewCars.setBounds(260, 20, 110, 20);

                add(viewRent);
                viewRent.setBounds(260, 50, 110, 20);

                add(viewBuy);
                viewBuy.setBounds(260, 80, 110, 20);

                add(viewAccessory);
                viewAccessory.setBounds(260, 110, 110, 20);
            }
        });

        viewCars.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new View();
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

and this is the second window that appears :

```java
package CarManager;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class View extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int width = 400;
    int height = width / 16 * 9;
    String title = "View all Cars";

    public View() {
        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(width, height);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res\\background2.jpg"));
        add(background);
        background.setSize(width, height);
    }
}
```

all i need is when i close the second window the first one to become visible again

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.*;


class View extends JFrame  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int width = 400;
int height = width / 16 * 9;
String title = "View all Cars";

    public View() {
    setLayout(null);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle(title);
    setSize(width, height);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res\\background2.jpg"));
    add(background);
    background.setSize(width, height);
   WindowListener listener = new WindowAdapter() {


   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent w) {

          new Main();

       }

      };

     addWindowListener(listener);
      }
    }
```

please run the program view.java i add Windows Adapter to get Windows Events when window close then main() windows shows

Comment: just be careful, that you do not create new instances of Main() as long as previous instances are still alive (but only invisible).

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own WindowAdapter:

```
public class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter {

    private Main mainFrame;         

    public MyWindowAdapter(Main mainFrame) {   // when creating an instance of this WindowAdapter, tell it with which Main Window you are working with
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);                 // when this WindowAdapter registers a closing operation it will set the Main Window visible again
    }
}
```

then when you crate your new `View` in the `actionPerformed()` you register a new instance of your own WindowAdapter and tell the window adapter what your `Main` instance looks like.

```
 viewCars.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            View view = new View();                         // your new View
            view.addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter(Main.this));   // register the WindowAdapter to your new View
            setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: ok it works but after i close the second window the first on appears visible as it should be , but the buttons are not visible, i have to hover over them for them to be displayed, why is that , and how to fix it ?

Comment: hm, that didn't happen in my test. Anyway, you could try forcing a repaint on the Main window: In `MyWindowAdapter` – `windowClosing()` add (under `mainFrame.setVisible(true);`) the line `mainFrame.repaint();`. This will give a notice to the `Main` window to repaint its components as soon as possible. Although this should not be necessary...tell me if it works

Comment: maybe `mainFrame.revalidate();` could do the trick.. but my guess is that it's your operating system, that causes that little bug.. maybe you have other instances of your program running somewhere in the background. I would try it again with a fresh restart and if the weired problem consists, ask a new question here in SO. Sorry, if I can't be of any more help here, but as I said, that doesn't happen when I run the code above – so I don't know where to look.